How to replace a pixel in a webGL canvas?
I want to change the color of one pixel for a webGL canvas by first getting the current value and then replace it with a new slightly modified color. For a 2d canvas context this was easy, but I quickly get lost trying to do the same for a webGl canvas context.
Here is my attempt at first reading the pixel color and then drawing it back with changed color. I would prefer just getting an array, change one value and then putting it back instead of drawing, but I found no way to do this either.
var gl = canvas.getContext('webgl');// get the context of Canvas or OffscreenCanvas
// allocate buffer
const out = new Uint8Array(4);
// read RGBA value of pixel
gl.readPixels(98, 122, 1, 1, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, out);
// change red value of pixel
out[0] = 255;
// convert changed array to Float32Array
var float32Data = new Float32Array(out);
// So far everything works but I don't know how to put the changed values back onto the canvas/context
var vbo = gl.createBuffer();
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);
gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, float32Data, gl.DYNAMIC_DRAW);
gl.vertexAttribPointer(1, 3, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
gl.drawArrays(gl.POINTS, 0, float32Data.length / 3);

EDIT
Added comments to clarify that getting the pixel color value works. I want to know how I can put the changed value back. Do I really have to draw? Can't I simply "edit" the underlaying data buffer/array?
For example, the 2d canvas has getImageData() and putImageData()
EDIT2
I am writing proxies for OffscreenCanvas.convertToBlob and canvas.toDataURL to alter the canvas before convertToBlob or toDataURL returns. For a 2d canvas getImageData and putImage data exist and serves my prurpose perfectly. Are there any equivalent for WebGL, changing a value in an underlaying buffer/array? The data returned by toDataURL and convertToBlob must still be valid objects

Do you need to read the pixel from the canvas output or is / can this be an offscreen rendering?

I need it to work for both Canvas and OffscreenCanvas. Both have the same context though? The WebGLRenderingContext. In my example the read of the pixel works fine, it is the change/overwrite I have problems with, thanks.

There's different approaches based on if you need to modify the image that's being output to the default framebuffer (screen/canvas) or not, and if you're using WebGL 1 or 2.

@LJ I made an other edit explaining my purpose and wanted result, I hope this clarifies things. I am not very familiar with GL (as I am sure you noticed) but I am hoping that there is an easier way to change just one pixel/vertex than writing 100 lines of code including shader programs

You could just draw the webgl canvas to another offscreen 2D canvas and then use the same code-path as you do for the 2D canvas:
const ctx = new OffscreenCanvas(1,1).getContext('2d');
export function applyProxy (canvas) {
  ['toDataURL', 'convertToBlob'].forEach(m=>{
    canvas[m] = (...args) => {
      // transfer image
      ctx.canvas.width = canvas.width;
      ctx.canvas.height = canvas.height;
      ctx.drawImage(canvas, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

      // modify pixel
      const x = 98,y = 122, imageData = ctx.getImageData(x,y,1,1);
      imageData.data[0] = 255;
      ctx.putImageData(imageData,x,y);

      // mimic original call
      return ctx.canvas[m](...args);
    }
  });
}

This solution should be rather efficient while also keeping code-complexity low.
If you insist on using WebGL you could use the scissor solution given in the answer you already got, its the least amount of code, albeit a bit hacky.
const x = 98, y = 122, out = new Uint8Array(4);
gl.readPixels(x, y, 1, 1, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, out);
out[0] = 255;

// get current state
const oldScissorRect = gl.getParameter(gl.SCISSOR_BOX);
const oldClearColor = gl.getParameter(gl.COLOR_CLEAR_VALUE);
const oldScissorEnabled = gl.isEnabled(gl.SCISSOR_TEST);

// "draw" the pixel
gl.enable(gl.SCISSOR_TEST);
gl.scissor(x, y, 1, 1);
gl.clearColor(out[0],out[1],out[2],out[3]);
gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

// restore state
gl.scissor(...oldScissorRect);
gl.clearColor(...oldClearColor);
if (!oldScissorEnabled) gl.disable(gl.SCISSOR_TEST);

Since WebGL is a state machine, to do this properly you have to ensure to restore the state afterwards, for that you have to query it from the driver like I do in the example, which can be slow, or cache it which is error prone. This is also the downfall of the "proper" WebGL solution as it does require setting up a shader and drawing a point thus requiring a lot of state memorization (assuming we need to be host application agnostic) which is why I won't make the effort of writing that out as it's impractical.

Thanks using clear was perfect, I only had to change the clearColor to float value and it works.

If I understand the question here is a solution.
First I draw in the canvas (I use a basic WebGL function, the scissor).
Then I run the drawing instructions again, but this time the destination is not the canvas, c'est à dire, the framebuffer(null), but a framebuffer with a texture attached.
gl.framebufferTexture2D(gl.FRAMEBUFFER,gl.COLOR_ATTACHMENT0,gl.TEXTURE_2D,copietextureEcran,0) 

Now this texture contains the drawing.
Then I build a WebGL code that reads this texture and draws a point at one of the coordinates.
if (gl_FragCoord.xy==vec2(3.5,3.5)) gl_FragColor=vec4(0,1,0,1);  



const canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
let width=7;
let height=7;
canvas.width=7;
canvas.height=7;
const gl = canvas.getContext('webgl');

function a() {
  gl.viewport(0, 0, width, height);
  gl.clearColor(1,0,0,1);
  gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
  gl.enable(gl.SCISSOR_TEST);
  gl.scissor(2, 2, 3, 3);
  gl.clearColor(1, 0, 1, 1);
  gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
  gl.disable(gl.SCISSOR_TEST);
  
  let copietextureEcran = gl.createTexture();
  gl.activeTexture(gl.TEXTURE0);
  gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, copietextureEcran);
  gl.texImage2D(
    gl.TEXTURE_2D,
    0,             
    gl.RGBA,
    width,
    height,
    0,
    gl.RGBA,
    gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE,
    null
  );  
  gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_S,gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);  gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_T,gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);  gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER,gl.NEAREST);  
  gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);  
  
  let fbEcran = gl.createFramebuffer();  
  gl.bindFramebuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER,fbEcran);  gl.framebufferTexture2D(gl.FRAMEBUFFER,gl.COLOR_ATTACHMENT0,gl.TEXTURE_2D,copietextureEcran,0);  
  
  gl.viewport(0, 0, 7, 7);  
  gl.clearColor(1,0,0,1);  
  gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);  
  gl.enable(gl.SCISSOR_TEST);  
  gl.scissor(2, 2, 3, 3);  
  gl.clearColor(1, 0, 1, 1);  
  gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);  
  gl.disable(gl.SCISSOR_TEST);
  
}
a();

function b() {  
  let vs=`  
    attribute vec2 aPosition;  
    varying vec2 vtexCoords;
    
    void main() {
      gl_Position=vec4(aPosition,0,1);
      vtexCoords = (aPosition+1.0)/2.0;
    }
  `;
  let fs=`  
    precision highp float;
    
    uniform sampler2D copietextureEcran;
    varying vec2 vtexCoords;
    
    void main() {
      vec4 color = texture2D(copietextureEcran,vtexCoords);
      gl_FragColor = vec4(color);  
      if (gl_FragCoord.xy==vec2(3.5,3.5)) gl_FragColor=vec4(0,1,0,1);
    }
  `;
  
  const vertexShader = gl.createShader(gl.VERTEX_SHADER);
  gl.shaderSource(vertexShader,vs);
  gl.compileShader(vertexShader);
  const fragmentShader = gl.createShader(gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER);
  gl.shaderSource(fragmentShader,fs);
  gl.compileShader(fragmentShader);
  const program = gl.createProgram();
  gl.attachShader(program,vertexShader);
  gl.attachShader(program,fragmentShader);
  gl.linkProgram(program);
  gl.useProgram(program);
  
  let positionAttributeLocation = gl.getAttribLocation(program, "aPosition");
  let positionBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER,positionBuffer);
  gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array([
        -1, -1,
        +1, -1,
        -1, +1,
        -1, +1,
        +1, -1,
        +1, +1,
        ]), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
   gl.enableVertexAttribArray(positionAttributeLocation);
   gl.vertexAttribPointer(positionAttributeLocation, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
   
   gl.bindFramebuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER,null);
   gl.viewport(0, 0, 7, 7);
   
   gl.clearColor(0,0,0,1);
   gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
   
   gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, 6);

}
canvas {
  width: 100x;
  height: 100px;
  image-rendering: pixelated;
 }
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
<button onclick="b()">Click me</button>




Please see my edit for clarification, I want something more inline with canvas 2d: getImageData() and putImageData().

@AndreasToresäter  link

thank you that looks like it is what I am after. I tried the example in the link but I get FRAMEBUFFER_INCOMPLETE_MISSING_ATTACHMENT or FRAMEBUFFER_INCOMPLETE_ATTACHMENT. It is not evident where the variable sTexture comes from, maybe I do it wrong, I simply tried sTexture = gl.createTexture()

gl.checkFramebufferStatus(gl.FRAMEBUFFER) does not return gl.FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE

@AndreasToresäter  gl.createTexture() is not enough, you need at least:  let texture = gl.createTexture(); gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture); // Fill the texture with a 1x1 blue pixel.   gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, 1, 1, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE,                 new Uint8Array([0, 0, 255, 255]));

-1 because your b solution is extremely inefficient while you already gave a better (but unconventional) solution in a (use the scissor and clear). And for posting "multiline" code in the comments.
